# bwoken: How to set output directory

Tags: testing, jenkins, ui-automation

I test my UI Automation on jenkins with bwoken, like this:

```
bwoken test
```

The Problem: The test results always appear in different subfolders, which correspond to the number of the run. The test results are expected in the folder integration/tmp/results. But then they are there again in subfolders like "Run 1", "Run 2", ...

In the next step I need to parse the test results to jUnit format. But I don't know how to get the corresponding file, if they are always in a subfolder.

So instead of having my files in "integration/tmp/results/Run x", I only want the newest - and only the newest - result in "integration/tmp/results/"

Any help how I could find/copy the corresponding file or how to tell bwoken where to put the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of bwoken here.

Bwoken doesn't currently provide a way to specify the output folder for a test run. Instruments itself actually chooses the names "Run 1", "Run 2", etc.

As a workaround, I'd suggest perhaps using a command like `ls -1tr integration/tmp/results/ | tail -1` to get the most recently modified directory name.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from clearing your workspace before each build starts; that way your output files will be in a predictable path.

You can then use that path to generate your jUnit results, and additionally tell Jenkins to archive the build output, jUnit results, or both (so that they're moved out of the workspace and into the results directory for safekeeping, before the next build wipes the workspace).

To do that, you might do something like:

- Enable the "Delete workspace before build starts" checkbox for the Jenkins job
- Run the job a few times, and make sure the output files are always found in `integration/tmp/results/Run 1`
- Set up your jUnit conversion step to operate on that path
- To archive files, in your job configuration, click `Add post-build action > Archive the artifacts`, and enter a pattern to archive the files you want to save. For example: `integration/tmp/results/Run 1/*`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the folder segregation (Run 1, Run 2,...) can be removed but there are other ways to get your work done. One such way would be to copy the file from the latest folder (for ex., Run N where N is the highest number folder) to another directory.

This means you simply have to find the latest file from directories which have a pattern "Run N" and copy it to another location (in this case, *integration/tmp/results/*).

I am assuming the following from your query:
1. That you are working on a *nix box
2. That it's just a single file getting published in each "Run N" folder.

Let's say,

```
[tom@jenkins ~]$ ls -ltr
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Sep 11 22:49 Run 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Sep 11 22:51 Run 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Sep 11 22:53 Run 3
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Sep 11 22:55 Run 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 Sep 11 22:57 testdir
```

So, just after the test results get published in "Run N" folder, you can run this one-liner to fetch the latest file and copy it to your destination dir.

```
cp "$(find . -type f -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | grep Run | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f9-)" .
```

You can modify the above command as per your requirement.